# Conjugate Gradient Method - undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: fortran

I started using fortran this year so i apologise if it is basic but i have been searching for a long time for an answer and i need to hand in tomorrow :( I keep getting the error:

```
Jamess-MacBook-Pro:Coursework2 james$ gfortran Question2cprogram.f90
gfortran: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘14.0.0
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___cg_solver_MOD_cg", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccg9ePxI.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It is a relatively simple program just subbing in values into a subroutine "cg" called from a module cg_solver.

```
program Question2c

use cg_solver
use numeric_kinds
use csr_sparse_matrix

implicit none

  real(dp) :: tol
  real(dp), dimension(:), allocatable :: x, b, real_x
  integer :: n, no_iterations
  type(sp_matrix) :: a

  n = 4

  allocate(real_x(n))
  real_x(1)=1
  real_x(2)=7
  real_x(3)=4
  real_x(4)=13

  allocate(b(n))
  b(1)=30.0
  b(2)=34.0
  b(3)=28.0
  b(4)=152.0

  allocate(x(n))

  allocate(a%matrix_entries(8))
  a%matrix_entries(1)=4.0
  a%matrix_entries(2)=2.0
  a%matrix_entries(3)=3.0
  a%matrix_entries(4)=1.0
  a%matrix_entries(5)=7.0
  a%matrix_entries(6)=2.0
  a%matrix_entries(7)=1.0
  a%matrix_entries(8)=11.0

  allocate(a%column_no(8))
  a%column_no(1)=1.0
  a%column_no(2)=4.0
  a%column_no(3)=2.0
  a%column_no(4)=4.0
  a%column_no(5)=3.0
  a%column_no(6)=1.0
  a%column_no(7)=2.0
  a%column_no(8)=4.0

  allocate(a%row_start(5))
  a%row_start(1)=1.0
  a%row_start(2)=3.0
  a%row_start(3)=5.0
  a%row_start(4)=6.0
  a%row_start(5)=9.0

  tol = 10**(-10)

  call cg(a,b,x,n,tol,no_iterations)

  print *, x

  deallocate(a)
  deallocate(x)
  deallocate(real_x)

end program Question2c
```

where the module cg_solver is given from the lecturer and works fine. I think the error may be in the way that i'm calling the module or something but i can't see what is wrong; they are all in the same folder.

Comment: How are you compiling the program? Are you linking the .o created by cg_solver?

Comment: Hi kyle, I'm typing "gfortran cg_solver.o question2cprogram.f90". the .o file is already created

Answer (score 0):

I've had better luck specifying the '-arch x86_64' flag for everything when using gfortran on OS X.

Might try recompiling all your files with that flag.